# C++ - recursive type or function dependency too complex

Tags: c++, templates

I try to compile the same code, but I succeed using g++ and failed when using msvc12. Here is the code:

```
template <typename T>
struct kernel_type
{
    typedef T ret;
};


template <typename TAG, typename A, typename B, unsigned OFFSET = 0>
struct binary_op_
{
    typedef typename kernel_type<A>::ret a1;
    enum
    {
        offset_a1 = 16 - ((16 - 1 + OFFSET) % 16) - 1,
        offset_a2 = 16 - ((16 - 1 + (OFFSET + offset_a1 + sizeof(a1))) % 16) - 1
    };
};
```

The error caused by the offset_a1 in offset_a2 expression, somehow the msvc12 compiler unable to derive offset_a1 expression. If I replace offset_a1 by its full expression, then the error is fixed. Anyone knows what happens here or I missed to change any settings in msvc12?

Comment: Causes will remain obscure, but two possible practical ways to deal with it: (1) upgrade compiler (it's currently at the 2014 version which is internal version number 19.00.xxxx which of old would mean version 13 but they skipped one high level version number so it's said to be version 14), or (2) using two separate enums may work, or not.

Comment: By the way it's generally not a good idea to use ALL UPPERCASE identifiers in C++, since they collide with the convention for macros. That may even be the problem, who knows. The Java/Python convention for constants is not suitable for C++, even though it originated with C, due to use of macros to express constants in that language.

Comment: What's `kernel_type`? I replaced `kernel_type<A>::ret` with `int`. Then it compiles with VS2013.

Comment: @Bent Wait, VS2013 uses msvc12, doesn't it? Then why am I able to compile while you are not?

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi, yup! I just added the kernel code, pls check it.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, thanks for suggestion! I will check the compiler version and try to upgrade if its old. I am using vs13 ultimate.

Comment: @Bent Still compiling. In search for a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we now have a C and an M but still miss the V. I guess the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi, wow that's cool! I will try again tomorrow, thanks for your time. :)